# if $\frac{m}{n},\frac{m+1}{n+2},\frac{m+2}{n+4},\frac{m+3}{n+6}$be positive integers, find the minimum of the m

Tags: number-theory

let $m$ be a positive integer,and $n$ be an  positive integers,such $$\dfrac{m}{n},\dfrac{m+1}{n+2},\dfrac{m+2}{n+4},\dfrac{m+3}{n+6}$$be positive integers,find the minimum of the $m$.

It seem use CRT to solve it? But I can't find it so far

Comment: You stipulate that n is even, but this has no solution in that case: m/n being an integer would imply that m is even, but (m + 1)/(n + 2) being an integer would imply that m is odd.

Comment: Is $n$ fixed, or do you want to find the minimum value of $m$ for which there is any solution at all (what Oscar did below)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If $\frac{m}{n}, \frac{m+1}{n+2}, \frac{m+2}{n+4}, \frac{m+3}{n+6}$ are all integers, so are $\frac{2m}{n}, \frac{2m+2}{n+2}, \frac{2m+4}{n+4}, \frac{2m+6}{n+6}$, and so are $\frac{2m-n}{n}, \frac{2m-n}{n+2}, \frac{2m-n}{n+4}, \frac{2m-n}{n+6}$. Hence $2m-n$ is a multiple of $\mbox{lcm}(n, n+2, n+4, n+6)$.

By Sridhar's comment, $n$ has to be odd, and by looking at the least common multiples of small $n$'s, the minimal l.c.m. is at $n=1$, hence $2m-1 \geq 105$, and $m\geq 53$. From Oscar's post we see that actually $m=53$ is the minimal solution!

Comment: For what it's worth, we can expand on the reasoning here to observe that, for a fixed n, the possible ms are precisely those of the form (k + 1/2) * n * (n + 2) * (n + 4) * (n + 6) / gcd(n, 3) + n/2.

Comment: Put another way, the solutions are precisely those of the form m = nH, where 2H = 1 mod n + 2, mod (n + 4)/gcd(n, 2), and mod (n + 6)/gcd(n, 3) simultaneously. When n is even, this is unsolvable, but when n is odd, they have the solution H = 1/2 + (n + 2)(n + 4)(n + 6)/gcd(n, 3) * (any odd number)/2.

Comment: We can go further.  Since $n$ is odd and $n,n+2,n+4,n+6$ differ by 2, 4, or 6 these arguments are pairwise relatively prime except possibly gcd$(n,n+6)=3$.  So the lcm is $n(n+2)(n+4)(n+6)/k$, with $k=3$ when $n$ is a multiple of 3, or $k=1$ otherwise (for odd $n$).  This relation assures that $n=1$ gives the minimal condition.  I was lucky in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

By brute force $53/1,54/3,55/5,56/7$ works, corresponding to $m=53,n=1$.  So the minimal $m$ can't be bigger than $53$.